# HSSF Apache POI Java Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

Tengo un código que básicamente me recorre una lista y lo mete en celdas utilizando la librería de `Apache POI`, pero se ve todo muy estrecho y no consigo darle un *padding* o algo para ensanchar celdas , dejo el código que tengo aquí.
Gracias!

```
HSSFWorkbook wk = new HSSFWorkbook();

Sheet dades = wk.createSheet(EEEE);

for (??? dades : ????) {
    Row header = dades.createRow(0);
    header.createCell(0).setCellValue(bla);
    header.createCell(1).setCellValue(nla);
    header.createCell(2).setCellValue(bla);

    Row rda = dades.createRow(rowNumDad);
    rda.createCell(0).setCellValue(dades.dades.getBla());
    rda.createCell(1).setCellValue(dades.dades.getBla());
    rda.createCell(2).setCellValue(dades.getBla());
    rowNumDad++;
}
```

Comment: Te aconsejo migrar de HSSF a XSSF, para trabajar con ficheros xlsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente éste es un tema peliagudo: la forma en que se define la anchura de la columna es en una extraña unidad: la anchura de un carácter en pixels dividida por 256. Dicha anchura, además, no puede ser superior a 255 caracteres.

Por supuesto, el tamaño de un carácter depende de la fuente y del tamaño de la misma, así como de la densidad de píxeles (dpi):

> To compute the actual number of visible characters, Excel uses the
>   following formula (Section 3.3.1.12 of the OOXML spec):
>
> ```
> width = Truncate([{Number of Visible Characters} * {Maximum Digit Width} + {5 pixel padding}]/{Maximum Digit Width}*256)/256.
> ```
>
> Using the Calibri font as an example, the maximum digit width of 11 point font
>   size is 7 pixels (at 96 dpi). If you set a column width to be eight
>   characters wide, e.g. setColumnWidth(columnIndex, 8*256), then the
>   actual value of visible characters (the value shown in Excel) is
>   derived from the following equation:
>   Truncate([numChars*7+5]/7*256)/256 = 8; which gives 7.29.

Por tanto tienes dos opciones:

En el objeto Sheet, tras meter todos los datos, usas la opción (el método) `autoSizeColumn(int columnIndex)`, que puede darte problemas si tienes muchas (miles) filas, porque comprobará primero qué fila tiene más caracteres para adaptarse y es un método lento.

Usas `setColumnWidth(int columnIndex, int width)` e intentas calcular el tamaño que debes usar por prueba y error.